# pygame circle animation

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a circle animation and want it to bounce inside the window just for practice. I was told that `pygame.draw.rect` returns a `Rect` object, however, I made this little code to see if it worked, and it didn't. The circle didn't move downwards one pixel per iteration like expected. What might be the problem?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 500), 0, 32)
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen.lock()
circleRect = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), (100, 200), 40)
screen.unlock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    circleRect.top += 1

    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(40)
```

Comment: Since this is just about the first task shown in the pygame tutorial, I suggest you read that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw the circle and update the rectangle in every frame. Hint: you need to slightly edit and move just one line

Ok, now you are drawing the circle correctly, but you're drawing it in the same position. Look carefully at the arguments you pass to draw.circle, where are you telling it to draw the circle?

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't quite understand what you mean ? Do you suggest that i should but the circle drawing function inside a while loop ? I tried that , and the circle still didn't move.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you're just drawing the circle to `(100, 200)` and storing the rect for later use (even though you never use it again).

```
screen.lock()
circleRect = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), (100, 200), 40)
screen.unlock()
```

You're catching the `rect` from the `blit` of the circle to the screen. It doesn't matter that later, you're moving `circleRect` around, because the `circleRect` is never used again. You would have to change your code so the circle is being drawn at the location of `circleRect`, instead of at `(100, 200)` every time.

```
circleRect= = pygame.Rect(100,200, 0, 0)
screen.lock()
circleRect = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), circleRect, 40)
screen.unlock()
```

and then, in your main loop, you'd need to redraw the circle with the same line as before, just under the adjustment of the `top` attrib:

```
circleRect.top += 1
circleRect = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), circleRect, 40)
```